# Load ViewController through hard code with storyBoardID

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm trying to load a view through this code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//let vc = self
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginView") as! RegistrationViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The result is:

```
2017-07-24 16:39:48.135 XXX [8689:286531] Warning: Attempt to present <XXX.RegistrationViewController: 0x7f8246206280> on <XXX.LaunchAppCheck: 0x7f8243d06bd0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I've already seen in another question to try with `viewDidAppear()`, but the problem still persist.

Comment: is this a warning or a crash ?

Comment: A warning: there's no crash. The app still remains on the first viewController 'cause it can't load the desired viewController as shown in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this line is bothering you:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

This is instantiating another storyboard other than your actual storyboard.

This is the code I use:

```
let vc: SettingsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You should not try to load it in simultaneously with another viewController, i.e. viewDidLoad() as at this point it is not on the stack yet.

If you really need to present 2 viewControllers at same time, try to call the second one using a delay:

```
vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
         self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Maybe it helps.

Don't forget to set the id of your view in your Identity Inspector.

[image]

Comment: It tells me that the constant "vc" has benne captured in a closure before being initialized.

Comment: I think there is some misplacement in your code as it runs "as is" in my app

Comment: you've forgotten to initialize the "vc" variable: as mentioned by me, it isn't initialized, only declared.

To work properly, it must be initialized as following:
vc=storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController.

Add this line before invoking the Dispatcher and I'll mark your answer as "accepted! :)

Comment: Ah. I understood what you mean. I have gave you 2 ways. The declaration and instance is on the first. The second I just made the call using dispatch. I will edit it